# 5 Diagonal Matrix and for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, eigen, allocation, diagonal

Is there an easier way to construct a 5 Diagonal matrix in Eigen? I can probably run for loops and allocate diagonals and zeros, but I did come across Diagonal<> just not sure how to use it for 5 diagonals, instead of one. Any ideas? EDIT: Figured this one out! For those wondering; you can use

```
matrix.diagonal(+n) = vector;
matrix.diagonal(-n) = vector;
```

to access super/sub diagonals of a matrix and write over them with vectors.

General side question: Is there a way I can skip an allocation when running a for loop in C++? For example:

```
int n; //size of matrix
MatrixXd m(n,n); //nxn matrix

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{ 
   m(i,i) = 5; 
   m(i,i+1) = 6;
   m(i,i-1) = 4;
   m(i,i+2) = 7;
   m(i,i-2) = 3;
}


for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
         if(m(i,j) = something) //I want the loop to skip m(i,j) where 
            break;              //i have already allocated values to m(i,j)
                                //How do I do that, in general, in C++?      
         else
       { m(i,j) = 0;}
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do not ask multiple questions at once! Read [ask]! Also, if you provide code, provide something which actually compiles and executes instead of vague pseudo-code. How is your second question related to allocation? I only see an assignment (but you don't say what `m` actually is).

Comment: @chtz sorry about that! Just getting started so getting used to the etiquette. As for m, m is a matrix, so m(i,j) would be the entries of the matrix.

Comment: You should split your question and don't put answers into the question (you are allowed to answer your own questions). Also, I still don't see how your second question relates to allocation.

Comment: @chtz Right! Thanks for your response, btw. I have re-edited my question and the code as well. Please see if you can understand my question better now. This is just one example, in general I might have matrix with different values along it's diagonals too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to skip the diagonals because they've already been initialized (allocated is not the correct term here).
Looking at your loop where you set the diagonals you can see that each (i,j) that you set obeys `abs(i-j) <= 2`. For example, when you set the element `(i, i+2) -> abs(i-(i+2)) -> abs(-2) -> 2` which is less than or equal to 2.

So the condition in your second loop should be:

```
if (abs(i-j) <= 2)
  continue;//break will exit the loop, continue will skip to the next iteration
```

Comment: Also, if the `else`-branch just assigns `0` it is likely more efficient to fill the entire matrix with `0` and overwrite the diagonals afterwards.

Comment: @SirGuy thank you. I actually ended up using Eigen's inbuilt functions to initialize sub/super diagonals, but this abs() method looks very useful too!